# UINavigationController size

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller

Is it possible to set a custom size for the UINavigationController view?
I need to embed a hierarical list into a view and I don't want the UINavigationController to be fullscreen.

Other solutions?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2962162/non-fullscreen-uinavigationcontroller

Answer (score 0):

You can create a UINavigationController and then position its view as a subview of something else.  For instance:

```
UINavigationController * nav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:root];

UIView * somethingElse = [self getSomethingElse];
[somethingElse addSubView:nav.view];
[nav setBounds:theBoundsWeWant];
[nav setFrame:theFrameWeWant];
```

The `bounds` and the `frame` properties will determine where the nav is shown on screen.