# UINavigationController as popover on iPhone?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, ios7

How can I present a UINavigationController with navigation bar like a popover **on iPhone** using custom UIViewController transitions introduced in iOS 7?
I accomplished this with a standard UIViewController and transition animator:

http://www.bytolution.com/Screenshot%202013.11.02%2015.25.34.png

When trying the same with UINavigationController instead, this is the result:

http://bytolution.com/Screenshot%202013.11.02%2015.27.10.png

At WWDC [session 218](https://developer.apple.com/wwdc/videos/) (login required) an Apple engineer made a demo of the exact thing I am trying to achieve:

http://bytolution.com/Screen%20Shot%202013-11-03%20at%2013.50.17.png

Unfortunately I could not find the sample code anywhere.

If you want to take a look at my code visit [Github.com/bytolution/Apsiape](https://github.com/bytolution/Apsiape)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Make a custom navigation bar, not a real one

Answer (score 1):

I would take a look at WYPopoperController which does what you want on iPhone: https://github.com/nicolaschengdev/WYPopoverController

Comment: Thanks for the hint! My only issue is that WYPopoverController doesn't use the new convenient APIs introduced in iOS 7 for custom view controller transitions. According to the WWDC session there must be a way I don't find :/ Sadly it seems like no one else encountered this problem or found a solution.

Answer (score 0):

iPhone does not support the UIPopoverController class and all Modal transitions are full screen. Yet obviously the screen shot you showed exists.

Any view controller can have its view extracted and shown within another view. That is what's been done there. A black view is placed over the background with 30% opacity and the "popover" view is added on top of that. For added effect, a tap gesture recognized can be added to the black masking view to dismiss the popover when the user taps off of it.

Comment: You should probably watch the session video to understand the introduced concept of "Custom View Controller Transitions". Using such trickery in a demo would defeat the purpose of the session.

Comment: You're right. My answer was not using the mechanisms they show in the WWDC video you referenced. A quick Google search found a great example [here](http://www.teehanlax.com/blog/custom-uiviewcontroller-transitions/).

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured out how to do it on my own. I refined my Google search and found the trick to be an ***embedded UINavigationController***. This was also useful for custom view controller transitions as it works nicely. You might want to check out [this stackoverflow.com question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2962162/non-fullscreen-uinavigationcontroller).

If you need the code, it's in my [project on GitHub](https://github.com/bytolution/apsiape).