# Is it posible for a paypalpaymentviewcontroller view to be placed inside a uiview?

Tags: ios, swift, paypal, viewcontroller

Is it posible for a paypalpaymentviewcontroller view to be placed inside a uiview? I have been trying this out for hours and I'm not getting any result. Is there any plugin that can let me implement the Paypal payment UI into my app view?
I think the question is straight forward enough.thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: It's just a `UINavigationController`, why not? similar to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2527441/2710486)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No it is not possible to placed inside a uiview.